# Numerically sort comma delimited string values of nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary:

```
some_dictionary = {
    "sub_dict1": {
        "miles": "5,024,279"
    },
    "sub_dict2": {
        "miles": "733,391"
    },
    "sub_dict3": {
        "miles": "7,151,502"
    }
}
```

I need to sort some_dictionary by the numerical values of miles so when I display it should be something like this:

```
"sub_dict2": {"miles": "733,391"},
"sub_dict1": {"miles": "5,024,279"},
"sub_dict3": {"miles": "7,151,502"}
```

My most recent attempt was:

```
top = OrderedDict(sorted(some_dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], "miles".replace(',', '')))
print(top)
```

This resulted in a TypeError. I'm pretty lost here, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can modify the dictionary before sorting it, you could convert the values to integers, or if you still need the separators, consider using the `_` (underscore) as it is interpreted as a thousands separator in Python, see here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
top = dict(sorted(some_dictionary.items(), key= lambda x: int(x[1]["miles"].replace(",", ""))))
```

You were missing square brackets around `"miles"` and you probably want to convert the string to int to do the comparison as a number.

Also, [since Python 3.7 default dictionary is ordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) so you don't have to use `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general approach:

```
sorted(some_dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: int(''.join([_ for _ in x[1]['miles'] if _.isdigit()])))
```

using the `.isdigit()` instead of the .replace is more general.
This solution cannot handle float numbers.